# Java Sping Data ленивая инициализация

Tags: java, spring

Есть приложение, в котором используется Spring Data, соответственно, имеются интерфейсы с аннотацией репозиторий, сервисы, их имплементирующие, с аннотацией сервис. В качестве пользовательского интерфейса используется Swing. Данные подгружаются через сервис из бд в пользовательское окно. Возникает ситуация, когда в зависимости от действий пользователя хотелось бы, используя связи , между таблицами базы данных, подгружать соответсвующие данные, соответственно, натыкаюсь на ошибку ленивой инициализации хибернейта. Почему это происходит я понимаю. Теперь хотелось бы понимать, какие возможные пути решения этой проблемы вообще существуют. Сразу прошу не предлагать очевидные штуки в духе изменить FetchType=EAGER, либо метода Hibernate.initialize(). Спасибо.

Comment: Кроме очевидных и [стратегии загрузки графа](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph) ничего и не осталось.

Comment: вот [тут](https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/09/05/the-hibernate-enable_lazy_load_no_trans-anti-pattern/) осуждают использование свойства `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans`, но вдруг.

Comment: Просто хочется уже как-то на новый уровень, чтобы один раз прописать нормально связи, все настроить и совсем базу данных не чувствовать, работать только с объектной моделью, а не получается... Все равно где-то приходится ручками.

Comment: значит объектная модель вам не подходит.

Comment: лично мне она всем подходит. мне не подходит то, как она стыкуется с бд